# Java: Implementing a new thread, now my code executes twice

Tags: java, multithreading, observer-pattern

I asked another question the other day about getting keyboard input while within a swing GUI--actually MCR input. One user found a low-level keyboard hook someone wrote. Very cool, and it mostly works. I had to learn some new things to implement it (always happy to do that), and tbh I may not be fully understanding what's going on.

Thing is, and I'll post the code below, it now runs through a while loop (while success == false, in CardRead.java) twice when I implement the thread for the keyboard hook. If I hard code sample data it only runs through once. If I delete the keyboard hook and use a normal Scanner.nextLine() (which means I have to click in the console to provide input to the application), it only runs through once. Start a new thread with an observer for keyboard input? Twice. I don't understand why, or how to fix it. I'd be happy with just understanding exactly what's going on-- if one of you all show me how to fix it, I'll be ecstatic.

Here's the code:

CardRead.java

```
public class CardRead {

public static String raw_card_data;

int readcount = 1;

String[] tracks = new String[2];
String[] tracks_final = new String[2];

public static void main() 
{
    // This doesn't happen until after card is swiped, dunno why.
    //GUI.outputArea.setText(GUI.outputArea.getText() + "\n\n Scan card \n");

    boolean success = false;

    while (success == false)
    {
        //raw_card_data = "%test?;testing?"; // <-- using this, runs thru once

        // using THIS, runs through twice.
        // create an event source - reads from stdin
        final KB_EventSource evSrc = new KB_EventSource();

        // create an observer
        final KB_RespHandler respHandler = new KB_RespHandler();

        // subscribe the observer to the event source
        evSrc.addObserver( respHandler );

        // starts the event thread
        Thread kb_thread = new Thread(evSrc);
        kb_thread.start();

        // sleep until card swiped
        while (raw_card_data == null)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        System.out.println(raw_card_data);

                // Tokenize raw_card_data
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(raw_card_data, "?");
        int i = 0;
        do
        {
            tracks[i] = tokenizer.nextToken();
            System.out.println(i + ": " + tracks[i]);
            i++;
        }
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens());
        //System.out.println(track1);
        //System.out.println(track2);
        tracks_final[0] = tracks[0].substring(1,tracks[0].length());
        if (tracks[1] != null)
        {
            tracks_final[1] = tracks[1].substring(1,tracks[1].length());
        }   
        if ( (readcount <= 5) && ( (tracks_final[0].equals("E") || tracks_final[0].equals(null) ) || (tracks_final[1].equals("E") || tracks_final[1].equals(null)) ) )
        {
            GUI.notout.setText("Card Read Unsuccessful. Scan Again.");
            GUI.outputArea.setText(GUI.outputArea.getText() + "Card read unsuccessful. Scan again. \n");
            success = false;
            readcount++;
        }
        else if (readcount <= 5)
        {
            GUI.notout.setText("Card Successfully Read");
            GUI.outputArea.setText(GUI.outputArea.getText() + "\n Success! \n");
            GUI.outputArea.setText(GUI.outputArea.getText() + "Track 1 = " + tracks_final[0] + "\n");
            GUI.outputArea.setText(GUI.outputArea.getText() + "Track 2 = " + tracks_final[1] + "\n");
            success = true;
        } // end if else chain
       } // end while success == false
} // end public void main
} // end class CardRead
```

KB_RespHandler.java

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

public class KB_RespHandler implements Observer 
{
private String resp;
    public void update (Observable obj, Object arg)
    {
        if (arg instanceof String) 
        {
            resp = (String) arg;
            CardRead.raw_card_data = resp;           
        }
    }
}
```

KB_EventSource.java

```
import de.ksquared.system.keyboard.*;
import java.util.Observable; 

public class KB_EventSource extends Observable implements Runnable
{
public static String temp = "";
public static String output = "";

public void run() 
{   

    new GlobalKeyListener().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() 
    {
        @Override public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event)
        { 
            switch(event.getVirtualKeyCode())
            {
            case KeyEvent.VK_0:
                if (event.isShiftPressed() == true)
                    temp += ")";
                else if (event.isShiftPressed() == false)
                    temp += "0";
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_1:
                if (event.isShiftPressed() == true)
                    temp += "!";
                else if (event.isShiftPressed() == false)
                    temp += "1";
                break;
            /*insert processing for other keys here*/
            case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
                if (event.isShiftPressed() == true)
                    temp += " ";
                else if (event.isShiftPressed() == false)
                    temp += " ";
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RETURN:
                /*if (event.isShiftPressed() == true)
                    temp += "\n";
                else if (event.isShiftPressed() == false)
                    temp += "\n";*/
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers(temp);
                //clearChanged();
                  break;                                                                        
            } // end switch (event.getVirtualKeyCode())*/
        } // end public void keyPressed
    });
    while(true)
    try 
    { 
        Thread.sleep(100); 
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e) 
    { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
}
```

So, I don't know what's going on. I was thinking maybe I need to stop the thread `kb_thread` after receiving input, but I can't find any way to do that. `thread.stop()` and `thread.destroy()` are deprecated and Eclipse and Google tell me not to use them. And that might not even be what I need to do anyway.

Comment: which while loop does it run through twice?

Comment: while (success == false), in CardRead.java. I'll edit the post to clarify that.

Comment: could you also post the code that sets success = true?

Comment: Alright, the rest of the code is there now

Comment: There's actually a little bit more code for manual card number entry, but I don't think it's relevant to this discussion

Comment: I have a slight suspicion that your while loop is actually looping through more than twice when using the thread  - can you confirm this for me?  You could just put some sort of counter var outside the while loop, increment it at the end of each loop and do a System.out.println of the counter.  Maybe you've already done this but just want to see if that might be the case...

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think about doing that. I've inserted printlns in various places, but let's try this with a counter.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6872/discussion-between-electrickoolaid42-and-zack-macomber)

Answer (score 0):

The comment in "CardRead.java" says "which upon success will change success = true".

Does this mean that it might fail, so it won't change `success`?

If that's true then `raw_card_data` would still be non-null, and it would try again.

I'm assuming that you resetting `raw_card_data` to null again at some point.

On another point, this:

```
if (event.isShiftPressed() == true)
    temp += ")";
else if (event.isShiftPressed() == false)
    temp += "0";
```

can be simplified to:

```
if (event.isShiftPressed())
    temp += ")";
else
    temp += "0";
```

Comment: I added the rest of the code in CardRead.java. I'm not resetting raw_card_data to null. And yes I could have simplified that if else chain. I realized that about halfway through typing out nearly identical code for every button on a standard keyboard, then decided it didn't matter. It's not worth going back to edit it when it works fine the way it is.

Comment: If it's unsuccessful reading the card, it'll just increment `readcount` and loop around, immediately trying again and failing. It'll loop forever. Try stepping through with a card which will fail.

Comment: Good observation. There's an extra if statement I didn't include in the code in the post b/c it deals only with manual card # entry, but it has its own loop for when readcount is > 5. It prompts the user to enter in the card info until proper info is entered, at which point it sets both success and another boolean called success_manual to true, exiting the manual entry loop and the outer loop. It will loop until it gets the necessary input one way or the other, it's made that way.